# Bounds for sum of the homological dimensions in the incidence algebra of a Boolean lattice

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra.
Define $\varphi_A:= \sup \{ \operatorname{pd} M + \operatorname{id} M \mid M \in \operatorname{ind}(A) \}$, where $\operatorname{pd} M$ denotes the projective dimension, $\operatorname{id} M$ the injective dimension and $\operatorname{ind}(A)$ the indecomposable $A$-modules.

> Question 1: Is there a good way to bound $\varphi_A$ or check whether it is bounded by the global dimension of $A$?

> Question 2: What is $\varphi_A$ for $A$ the incidence algebra of the Boolean lattice of an $n$-set? Is it equal to $n=\operatorname{gldim} A$ (this is true for $n=1,2$)?

Comment: You ought to work on your LaTeX skills. Most mathematicians who use LaTeX for decades are unaware of some of the most obvious things about LaTeX, but this one was worse than that, and this from a person who's posted over 500 questions here.